# How to write integration tests for spring boot rest API using wiremock, rest assured, Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured, spring-boot-test, wiremock

I have a basic spring boot project rest api and i want to write integration tests for my rest api. Tech stack: wiremock, restassured, Junit5.  How to proceed further.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user already had the answer up front. He posted the answer at the same time he asked the question

Comment: yes, i had the answer. It took me two days to get this answer after searching whole the internet. Now it under one question to help future to save them time

Comment: Then at least add more details to the question because now it does not meet the SO guidelines for asking. It's far too general

Answer (score 0):

1. First add related dependency's in pom file

   ```
       <!-- Testing -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
       <version>2021.0.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
       <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
       <version>2.31.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.epages</groupId>
       <artifactId>restdocs-api-spec-restassured</artifactId>
       <version>0.16.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a base integration test class

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.JsonConfig;
import io.restassured.config.LogConfig;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.path.json.config.JsonPathConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//To start the stub server on random port, use a value of 0
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs ="classpath:/stubs")
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "external-service.host=http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}"
})
@Import(BaseIntegrationTestClass.TestConfig.class)
public class BaseIntegrationTestClass {

    @LocalServerPort
    int serverPort = 0;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpRestAssured() {
        RestAssured.port = serverPort;
        RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.newConfig()
                .jsonConfig(JsonConfig.jsonConfig().numberReturnType(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE))
                .logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig().enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails());
    }
//override beans of your choice
   @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public WebServiceTemplate mockWebServiceTemplate() {
            WebServiceTemplate template = mock(WebServiceTemplate.class);
            when(template.getDefaultUri()).thenReturn("/hello");
            return template;
        }

    }
}
```

3. Write your test classs

```
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class RestControllerIT extends BaseIntegrationTestClass{

    @Test
    public void testStatusCodePositive() {
        Response response =  RestAssured.given().
                when().
                get("/");
        assertThat(response.statusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
        assertThat(response.body().asString(), equalTo("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

4. your controller

```
import service.ExternalApiService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class YourController {

    @Autowired
    private ExternalApiService externalApiService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String checkEligibility() {
       return this.ExternalApiService.go();
    }

}
```

5. your service

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class ExternalApiService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${external-service.host}")
    private String base;

    ExternalApiService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String go() {
        return this.restTemplate.getForEntity(this.base + "/activities", String.class)
                .getBody();
    }
}
```

1. Inside src/main/resources -> application.properties file you have

```
external-service.host="https://example.org"
```

2. Inside src/test/resources/stubs folder you have a json mapping for url same as rest template url. somename.json

```
    {
  "request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/activities",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

```
// for urls with path params /car/garage/{garageNum}/location/{locationNum}
{
  "request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/car/garage.*/location.*",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
     "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
       "jsonBody": 
     {
     "msg": "hello world",
     }
  }
}
```

8. right click on It test file and run
9. Add plugin in build section to generate report

```
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>merge-unit-and-integration</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>merge</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-merged-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-merged</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```